# app.post and the express-fileupload dependency is producing no response

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple html uploading form

```
<h1>Upload File Here</h1>

<form methods="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
  <input type="file" name="filename" /> <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

I want uploaded files to hit a "/upload" folder. I am using the following express code to do this.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
upload = require("express-fileupload");

app.listen(80);

app.use(upload());

console.log("Server Started");
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  if (req.files) {
    var file = req.files.filename,
      filename = file.name;
    file.mv("/upload/" + filename, err => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send("error occured");
      } else {
        res.send("done!");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

When I start the server and go to `localhost` in Chrome, I see the upload form. If I try to upload something, the url box changes to reflect the file I tried to upload, but the file does not appear in the '/upload' folder. Any ideas on what obvious mistake I'm making??

Thanks!

The solution is in my form. I need to set the `action="http://localhost:80/upload"`

New HTML is

```
<h1>Upload File Here</h1>

<form
  ref="uploadForm"
  id="uploadForm"
  action="http://localhost:80/upload"
  method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
  <input type="file" name="filename" /> <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in my form. I need to set the

```
action="http://localhost:80/upload"
```

New HTML is

```
<h1>Upload File Here</h1>

<form
  ref="uploadForm"
  id="uploadForm"
  action="http://localhost:80/upload"
  method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
  <input type="file" name="filename" /> <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```